# External user with personal email

Tags: office-365, user

I am trying to share a portal site with a few clients and allow them to use their own email address.
(via office 365 plan E3 if that matters)

I went to the admin center -> `site collections` -> `settings` -> `Manage external users`

I selected Allow and clicked save.

Now in the client portal, `site actions` -> `share site`, it still says:

> Invitations to users outside your organization are currently disabled.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Which plan are you on?

Comment: E3 (short comment bad)

Comment: can you share documents with external users in sharepoint 2013 on-premise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague figured it out.

What was missing was the per-site setting.

At the site, go to `Site Actions` -> `Site Settings` -> `Site Collection Administration` -> `Site collection features` -> `External user invitations` -> `Activate`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry when I asked that question I forgot that they updated the PALs earlier this year, my bad.

**Plan P** : 500 (Fixed)

**Plan E** : 10,000 (Business desk escalation)

**Dedicated**: 10,000 (Purchasable PAL Packs)

PALs are reusable if you delete the account in which is using up the PAL, so administration is key to small businesses.

---

Go to your SharePoint Online administration panel http://sitename-admin.sharepoint.com

Click "**Manage Site Collections**"

Click "**Settings**" on the Ribbon and then "**Manage External Users**"

Select "**Allow**" on the radio button on the popup.

Done.

You have 50 licences with your plan as basic, then extra as you move up plans + you can buy more.